# How to delete one attribute in multiple entries in LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an attribute "lastDateConnection" in my objectClass "person" that was move to the database (for stats,cache and performance reason).
This duplication causes confusion.

For one entry, I simply need to do this:

```
dn: uid=joe,ou=people,ou=application,dc=client,dc=fr
changetype: modify
delete: dateLastConnection
```

But How can I do this for all the persons in my LDAP?

Here some of my fails: :)

```
#!RESULT ERROR
#!DATE 2018-03-26T13:24:47.588
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 53 - no global superior knowledge]
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
delete: dateLastConnection
```

or

```
#!RESULT ERROR
#!DATE 2018-03-26T13:26:08.755
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 17 - changetype: attribute type undefined]
dn: cn=schema
changetype: add
objectClass: personn
changetype: modify
delete: dateLastConnection
```

Thank you,
Amaury

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete it from the schema while there are entries that have it set. You have to delete it *from those entries*, which requires a modify operation per such entry.

Comment: So I first need to get all username, and after loop on each entry to remove the attribute? Can it be done in one ldif?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Suppression des attributs dateLastConnection"

for i in `ldapsearch -x -h localhost:389 -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=client,dc=fr" -w "changeme" -b "ou=people,ou=app,dc=client,dc=fr" -s sub "(objectclass=person)" | grep uid=| cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/^\ //g'`
do

ldapmodify -x -h localhost:389 -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=client,dc=fr" -w "changeme" << EOF
dn: $i
changetype: modify
delete: dateLastConnection


EOF

done
```

Thank you EJP